# ImageButton issues. Skipped 35 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, imagebutton

I'm making a new post because I don't know how to solve the problem I have. I've read many posts but I didn't find right solution. I have only one ImageButton and I get an error "Skipped 66 frames! The application ...". I heard about AsyncTask but I don't know how to use it so this is why I am writing this post. I saw AsyncTask solutions but not for ImageButton so I would like to get an example for ImageButton to solve my problems for my app.
Thanks alot.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ImageButton info;
Button playButton;
TextView title;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //FULLSCREEN
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    info = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info);
    info.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.info);
}
```

}

Comment: What is the size of "info" image in pixel?

Comment: The size is 500x500

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use third party libraries to cache and load big images into your views and not do it on the main thread. Research Glide, Picasso and the likes. For example, with Glide you can load images asynchronously like this:

```
Glide.with(this).load(imagePath).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(viewWidth, viewHeight) {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
                            yourImageButton.setBackground(drawable);
                    }
});
```

Comment: I resized all images to size 500x500 just because of that problem but I will try this, thanks.

Comment: @ElNiinjos that is probably the better solution if you don't need to worry about the size. However, if you like to keep a larger drawable to be able to support larger screen sizes, then you either have to create all drawable manually or resize them on the go using the method above

Comment: Is it better to do this with object or another method in main class? I tried to initialize and return image button in another class but I didn't fix the problem.

Comment: info = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.info);
        init();
    }

    public void init(){
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.info).asBitmap().into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(500, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                Drawable info_draw = new BitmapDrawable(resource);
                info.setBackground(info_draw);
            }
        });
    }
}

Is this ok now? I think its a litle bit better because I get just one error and not two but its not perfectly ok.

Comment: that looks okay. you can use other tricks to speed it up even more. you can use .thumbnail() or .placeholder() or other loading tricks. However, if you are still seeing that error for a 500x500 image (presumably .png), then you have another problem. That is not a big image size to be the cause of that issue.

Comment: I realized what was the problem. I set the background of layout in java with glide, now works without any skipped frames.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid doing this on UI thread, you could set the background resource in activity_main.xml. something like this:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/info" />
```

Comment: this will not help. loading sources will still happen on the ui thread

Comment: I tried this before but it's the same. The main problem I have is that I'm working on app with 35 files in drawable and for every click on button, the image change so I get 400 - 600 skipped frames and on my phone doesn't work normally.

Comment: @ElNiinjos if you have 35 images to load you definitely need to do them asynchronously. Glide or Picasso are your best bets

Answer (score 0):

You should check and resize the dimension of your "R.drawable.info" image.